# Is this Javascript (Tabify and basic JS) conflicting?

Tags: javascript

For some reason tabify http://unwrongest.com/projects/tabify/ does not work when I have my other script running below.If I delete everything above the calls to the tabify instances it works fine. That seems like basic js to me, not sure what would cause tabify not to run.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var $temp = $('h1').html();
    var myLabel = document.getElementById("mySpan");
    myLabel.innerHTML = $temp;
    document.getElementById('myInput').value= $temp;
    $('#tabmenu').tabify();
    $('#tabmenu2').tabify();
    });

    </script>
```